# Aggregate function (small) returns zeros rather than the smallest values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using excel's aggregate (small) function to find the smallest value for each name that appears in a column. The issue is that the formula below simply returns 0s everywhere there is a value in B.

The formula I am using is

```
=IF($B2<>"", AGGREGATE(15,7, ($B:$B)*($A2=$A:$A)*($B2<>""), 1), "")
```

where B contains the data I want the smallest value from and A contains identifying strings.

I appreciate any help you can lend!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to divide by the criteria:

```
=IF($B2<>"", AGGREGATE(15,7, ($B:$B)/(($A2=$A:$A)*($B:$B<>"")), 1), "")
```

Whenever `($A2=$A:$A)` or `($B2<>"")` is `FALSE` it will return `0` and anything multiplied by `0` is `0` and as such the smallest value is `0`.

By dividing by the criteria we throw an `#DIV/0` error which the `7` in the AGGREGATE's second criterion forces the formula to ignore and as such we only get the smallest of what returns `TRUE` or `1` in both Boolean. `1*1=1`.

But one more thing.  AGGREGATE is an array type formula so limiting the to only the data will speed it up.

```
=IF($B2<>"", AGGREGATE(15,7, ($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A)))/(($A2=$A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A)))*($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A))<>"")), 1), "")
```

---

As per your comment:

```
=IF($B2 = AGGREGATE(15,7, ($B:$B)/(($A2=$A:$A)*($B:$B<>"")), 1),AGGREGATE(15,7, ($B:$B)/(($A2=$A:$A)*($B:$B<>"")), 1), "")
```

Comment: You are the master of excel. Is there way to only make the smallest value show up once per Identifying String? Like in the picture, how the expected value for IS 2-7 only shows up next to the corresponding 4 in column B?

Comment: yes there is.   Apparently Scott got an answer up before I could comment.  I was going to say tack on a COUNTIF so the result would only appear beside the first occurrence....Apparently there more way than one to skin a cat! 8)

Comment: So, you were right that excel trying to calculate the third formula is _glacial!_ And excel is having to shut itself down too often. If you have the time, can you explain the logic of the second formula to me? I am a bit lost. Thank you again for all of your help!

Comment: Each time you do `($A2=$A:$A)` it will do 1.04 million calculations.  so that one formula alone does over 6 million calculations.  This is the problem with Array formulas.  If you have 1000 of these formula then it would equate to over 6 billion calculations.  But if you limit the reference to the data set then it is only doing 6000*1000=6,000,000 again.  The Match returns the last cell in column A that has text and sets that as the end point so it is dynamic but limits it to the last cell of the dataset.

Comment: Got it! And MATCH("zzz", . . .) just defaults to the last value in the column?

So, I can just combined the Index-Match equation with the third equation?

I really appreciate all the help you have given me, Scott!