# Finding first lowest value

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UiXM.png)This is in reference to: [Aggregate function (small) returns zeros rather than the smallest values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204699/aggregate-function-small-returns-zeros-rather-than-the-smallest-values)

I saw these formulas and wonder if a version of them could work in my situation:

```
A2=$A:$A)*($B:$B<>"")), 1),AGGREGATE(15,7, ($B:$B)/(($A2=$A:$A)*($B:$B<>"")), 1), "")

INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A)))*($B$1:INDEX($B:$B,MATCH("zzz",$A:$A))<>"")), 1), "")
```

I am trying to get this formula to work for me:

```
`=IFERROR(INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$G$3:$G$366957,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A$1:$A$366957)/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A$1:$A$366957=$A318)/(([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C$3:$C$366957<=$B318+IF($I318<=$H318,-M$1,M$1))),1))-$G318,"")`
```

This formula is in a file called 11-02 and a separate file is generated for each day, i.e., 11-03, 11-04, etc. OMAS is the MAIN file of all stocks from the stock market from each day. The following is a list of columns in OMAS:

A = SYM – List of stocks: A, AA, AAP, etc

B = LAST – The closing price of a stock for the day.

C = LOW – The lowest price of the stock for the day.

D = HIGH – The highest price of the stock for the day.

E = DIFF – D-C

F = OPEN – Opening price of stock.

G = DATE – Date

H = BUY – B-C

I = SELL – D-B

11-02 has the exact same columns, but is much smaller.

I am trying get the first value in Column C of OMAS, which is lower than B318 + M1 of 11-02, which in this case is “1”. Columns M1 – AA1 are numbered 1 - 15.

The determination for this formula is I<H in 11-02. I have sorted the file according to this formula, i.e., All stocks where I<H are together, as are all I>H.

This formula works in 11-02 if H>I:
`=IFERROR(INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$G$2:$G$366957,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A$1:$A$366957)/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A$1:$A$366957=$A16)/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D$2:$D$366957>=$B16+IF($I16>=$H16,T$1,-T$1)),1))-$G16,"")`

Which is what I tried to alter, to see if it would work if I<H, but so far I haven’t had any luck. I did break up this formula and used 3 helper columns, but it not only takes up an enormous amount of space (an extra 45 columns!), but takes forever to compute, because they're array formulas {}.

I used versions of these formulas in a file, in which I combined the OMAS and 11-02 into 1 file and it seemed to work ok, but not when I have 2 files. ANY help ANYONE can provide would be very much appreciated.

I have uploaded the files at:https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1331382-number-of-days-it-took-a-stock-to-rise-sink-above-a-certain-level.html#post5458971

I would upload the files here but I have no idea how to do that.
Thanks in advance,
Cliff

P.S. I guess I should explain what I am trying to accomplish. In the daily download, say 11-02, I find a value in Column A (SYM), which in this explanation is "LMPX" in A2. I want to add M-AA to B2, which would be B2+1 if "M" is chosen. I then see which is higher, either H2 or I2. Since I2 is higher, I want to find the first lowest value that is >= in column D of OMAS. If H2 were higher, I would like to find the next lowest value in column C of OMAS. In this example, B2+1 is 21.82, so I want to find the next lowest value in Column D in OMAS that is >= 21.82, which would be "24.87". Then I want to move to the corresponding date in column G, which would be 11/3. I then subtract G2 of 11-02 and subtract it from 11/3, which would leave 1. That is the value I am looking for...how many days it took for the stock to get higher/lower depending upon whether H2 or I2 is higher.

I know this is hard to understand so if anyone has any questions, please ask, because I really need help with this. I have been working on it for 4 or 5 months and it's driving me crazy.

[NEW SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UiXM.png)

Comment: In order to download the file one should log in the site. I don't think anyone take the time to create a new profile just to download a file. You can post images of your data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Evil Blue Monkey. I updated my question to hopefully make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### FORMULA SOLUTION

It was quite hard to understand what you are looking for. I hope i got it. Here is my formula for cell M2 of your "Book10" (the short daily file):

```
=IFERROR((IF($H2<$I2,INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$G:$G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D>$B2+M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1))-$G2,"")&IF($H2>$I2,INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$G:$G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C<$B2-M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1))-$G2,""))*1,"")
```

Chopping it into pieces we obtain this:

```
=IFERROR(                                                       'In case of error, nothing will be shown.
         (                                                       'This brackets is to multiply the result by one to turn it into a number.
          IF(
             $H2<$I2,                                            'If "Buy" is greater than "Sell"
             INDEX(                                              'we target
                   [0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$G:$G,                         'a cell in the column G of 0MAS
                   AGGREGATE(                                    'with
                             15,                                 'the smallest
                             6,                                  'valid value
                             ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)           'thanks to their row (in column D)
                             *1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D>$B2+M$1)   'filtered according to the cells that contains a value greater than Last plus the M-AA extra,
                             *1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)   'that is not a header (text) and
                             *1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),      'has the same Symbol of the actual row.
                             1
                            )
                  ) - $G2,                                       'Such cell has a date value that we subtract to the cell in the column G of the actual row.
             ""
            )
          &
          IF(
             $H2>$I2,                                            'If "Sell" is greater than "Buy"
             INDEX(                                              'we target
                   [0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$G:$G,                         'a cell in the column G of 0MAS
                   AGGREGATE(                                    'with
                             15,                                 'the smallest
                             6,                                  'valid value
                             ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)           'thanks to their row (in column C)
                             *1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C<$B2-M$1)   'filtered according to the cells that contains a value smaller than Last minus the M-AA extra,
                             *1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)   'that is not a header (text) and
                             *1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),      'has the same Symbol of the actual row.
                             1
                            )
                  ) - $G2,                                       'Such cell has a date value that we subtract to the cell in the column G of the actual row.
             ""
            )
         ) * 1,                                                  'The result is multiplied to return a number.
         ""
        )
```

As you can see, there will be no result if "Buy" is equal to "Sell".

**Bonus formula**

You can use this formula for a feedback on what cell the formula is targeting:

```
=IF($H2<$I2,"Targeting cell D","")&IF($H2>$I2,"Targeting cell C","")& IFERROR((IF($H2<$I2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D>$B2+M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1),"")&IF($H2>$I2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C<$B2-M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1),""))*1,"") & " (value " & IFERROR((IF($H2<$I2,INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$G:$G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D>$B2+M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1)),"")&IF($H2>$I2,INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$G:$G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C<$B2-M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1)),""))*1,"") & "), Sybol: " & IFERROR(IF($H2<$I2,INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D>$B2+M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1)),"")&IF($H2>$I2,INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C<$B2-M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1)),""),"")&", Low: " & IFERROR(IF($H2<$I2,INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D>$B2+M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$D:$D)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1)),"")&IF($H2>$I2,INDEX([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C<$B2-M$1)*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1)),""),"") & ", Starting data: " & $A2 & ", " & $B2 & ", " & $G2 & ", " & $H2 & ", " & $I2 & ", " & $M1
```

---

---

---

### VBA SOLUTION

Try this code:

```
Sub SubFirstLowestValue()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim WksSource As Worksheet
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim WksRecord As Worksheet
    Dim RngRecord As Range
    Dim RngRecordList As Range
    Dim WksResult As Worksheet
    Dim RngResult As Range
    Dim BytExtraMargin As Byte
    Dim BytExtraMarginMin As Byte
    Dim BytExtraMarginMax As Byte
    Dim DblSourceIndex As Double
    Dim DblSourceIndexCount As Double
    Dim RngSourceSYMBOL As Range
    Dim RngSourceLAST As Range
    Dim RngSourceDATE As Range
    Dim RngSourceBUY As Range
    Dim RngSourceSELL As Range
    Dim RngRecordSYMBOL As Range
    Dim RngRecordLOW As Range
    Dim RngRecordHIGH As Range
    Dim RngRecordDATE As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim StrExistingAutoFilterAddress As String
    Dim StrSYMBOL As String
    Dim StrDATE As String
    Dim BytCounter01 As Double
    Dim BlnStatusBar As Boolean
    
    'Settings.
    Set WksSource = ActiveSheet
    Set RngSource = WksSource.Range("A2")
    Set WksRecord = ActiveSheet
    
    'Checking for eventual autofilter.
    If WksRecord.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        'Setting StrExistingAutoFilterAddress.
        StrExistingAutoFilterAddress = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address
    End If
    
    'Removing eventual autofilter.
    WksRecord.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngRecord = WksRecord.Range("A2")
    Set RngRecordList = WksRecord.Range(RngRecord, RngRecord.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    Set WksResult = ActiveSheet
    Set RngResult = WksResult.Range("M1")
    Set RngSourceSYMBOL = WksSource.Range("A2")
    Set RngSourceLAST = WksSource.Range("B2")
    Set RngSourceDATE = WksSource.Range("G2")
    Set RngSourceBUY = WksSource.Range("H2")
    Set RngSourceSELL = WksSource.Range("I2")
    Set RngRecordSYMBOL = WksRecord.Range("A2")
    Set RngRecordLOW = WksRecord.Range("C2")
    Set RngRecordHIGH = WksRecord.Range("D2")
    Set RngRecordDATE = WksRecord.Range("G2")
    BytExtraMarginMin = 1
    BytExtraMarginMax = 15
    DblSourceIndexCount = RngSource.End(xlDown).Row - RngSource.Row
    
    'Setting an autofilter on RngRecordList.
    RngRecordList.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(RngRecordList.Rows.Count + 1, RngRecordList.Columns.Count).AutoFilter
    
    'Compiling extra margins' list headers.
    For BytCounter01 = 0 To (BytExtraMarginMax - BytExtraMarginMin)
        RngResult.Offset(0, BytCounter01).Value = "+-" & BytExtraMarginMin + BytCounter01
    Next
    
    'Resetting RngResult.
    Set RngResult = RngResult.Offset(1, 0)
    
    'Sorting RngRecordList.
    With WksRecord.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Intersect(RngRecordList, RngRecordSYMBOL.EntireColumn), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Intersect(RngRecordList, RngRecordDATE.EntireColumn), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange RngRecordList
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        .SortFields.Clear
    End With
    
    'Setting status bar.
    BlnStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    
    'Covering the whole list in WksSource.
    For DblSourceIndex = 1 To DblSourceIndexCount
        
        'Refreshing status bar message.
        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & Round(DblSourceIndex / DblSourceIndexCount * 100, 0) & "% (" & DblSourceIndex & " of " & DblSourceIndexCount & ")"
        
        'Clearing the result row.
        For BytExtraMargin = BytExtraMarginMin To BytExtraMarginMax
            RngResult.Offset(0, BytExtraMargin - BytExtraMarginMin).Value = ""
        Next
        
        'Filtering RngRecordList for the given symbol if changed.
        If RngSourceSYMBOL <> StrSYMBOL Then
            RngRecordList.AutoFilter Field:=RngRecordSYMBOL.Column - RngRecordList.Column + 1, Criteria1:=RngSourceSYMBOL.Value
            StrSYMBOL = RngSourceSYMBOL.Value
        End If
        
        'Filtering RngRecodlist for the given date if changed.
        If RngSourceDATE <> StrDATE Then
            RngRecordList.AutoFilter Field:=RngRecordDATE.Column - RngRecordList.Column + 1, Criteria1:=">" & Month(RngSourceDATE.Value) & "/" & Day(RngSourceDATE.Value) & "/" & Year(RngSourceDATE.Value)
            StrDATE = RngSourceDATE.Value
        End If
        
        'Checking if RngSourceBUY is greater than RngSourceSELL or vice versa.
        Select Case True
            Case Is = RngSourceBUY < RngSourceSELL
                
                'Covering each visible (alias: unfiltered) cell in the "High" column of RngRecordList.
                For Each RngTarget In RngRecordList.Columns(RngRecordHIGH.Column - RngRecordList.Column + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    
                    'Covering each extra margin.
                    For BytExtraMargin = BytExtraMarginMin To BytExtraMarginMax
                        
                        'Checking if the given cell's value is bigger than the value of RngSourceLAST plus the given extra margin.
                        If RngTarget.Value > RngSourceLAST + BytExtraMargin And RngResult.Offset(0, BytExtraMargin - BytExtraMarginMin).Value = "" Then
                            
                            'Reporting the dates' difference between the given row in the RngRecordList and the date in RngSourceDATE.
                            RngResult.Offset(0, BytExtraMargin - BytExtraMarginMin).Value = WksRecord.Cells(RngTarget.Row, RngRecordDATE.Column).Value - RngSourceDATE.Value
                            
                        End If
                        
                        'If all the results for the given row has been specified, the code is skipped to CP_Result_row_filled.
                        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(WksResult.Range(RngResult, RngResult.Offset(0, BytExtraMarginMax - BytExtraMarginMin))) = 0 Then GoTo CP_Result_row_filled
                        
                    Next
                Next
                
            Case Is = RngSourceBUY > RngSourceSELL
                
                'Covering each visible (alias: unfiltered) cell in the "Low" column of RngRecordList.
                For Each RngTarget In RngRecordList.Columns(RngRecordLOW.Column - RngRecordList.Column + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    
                    'Covering each extra margin.
                    For BytExtraMargin = BytExtraMarginMin To BytExtraMarginMax
                        
                        'Checking if the given cell's value is smaller than the value of RngSourceLAST minus the given extra margin.
                        If RngTarget.Value < RngSourceLAST - BytExtraMargin And RngResult.Offset(0, BytExtraMargin - BytExtraMarginMin).Value = "" Then
                            
                            'Reporting the dates' difference between the given row in the RngRecordList and the date in RngSourceDATE.
                            RngResult.Offset(0, BytExtraMargin - BytExtraMarginMin).Value = WksRecord.Cells(RngTarget.Row, RngRecordDATE.Column).Value - RngSourceDATE.Value
                            
                        End If
                        
                        'If all the results for the given row has been specified, the code is skipped to CP_Result_row_filled.
                        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(WksResult.Range(RngResult, RngResult.Offset(0, BytExtraMarginMax - BytExtraMarginMin))) = 0 Then GoTo CP_Result_row_filled
                        
                    Next
                Next
        End Select
CP_Result_row_filled:
        
        'Setting the variables for the next row in WksSource.
        Set RngSourceSYMBOL = RngSourceSYMBOL.Offset(1, 0)
        Set RngSourceLAST = RngSourceLAST.Offset(1, 0)
        Set RngSourceDATE = RngSourceDATE.Offset(1, 0)
        Set RngSourceBUY = RngSourceBUY.Offset(1, 0)
        Set RngSourceSELL = RngSourceSELL.Offset(1, 0)
        Set RngResult = RngResult.Offset(1, 0)
        
    Next
    
    'Restoring eventual previous autofiler.
    WksRecord.AutoFilterMode = False
    If StrExistingAutoFilterAddress <> "" Then
        WksRecord.Range(StrExistingAutoFilterAddress).AutoFilter
    End If
    
    'Resetting status bar.
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = BlnStatusBar
    
    
End Sub
```

The code can be costumized, but right now it's designed to be used on the active sheet that will contain a single list that will be both the "records" list (say the 0MAS file) as well as the list of starting data (say the Book10 file). To test it:

1. open 0MAS file;
2. copy-paste the code in a VBA module;
3. select the MAS sheet;
4. start the code.

You will most likely have to change the extension of the file from .xlsb to .xlsm in order to keep the macro.

Comment: Thank you S-O very much. I will try it and see if it will work on my actual files and let you know if I have any problems. I ESPECIALLY love the way you broke down the formula and explained what each part does. You have no idea how great that is for someone who knows just the basics of Excel.

Comment: Evil Blue Monkey, Again, thank you so much for the effort, but the formula didn't work correctly. I tried it on 2 versions of 11-02...a stand-along version and 1 that is attached to OMAS as a sheet. In the first version, I got a value of "0" and a "2" on the sheet version. Is it possible for you to send your email address to me at ATC1114@COX.NET and I will send you copies of the files so you can see what I am working with. I would send them via this forum but they're too large. THX

Comment: My hypothesis is: in the stand-alone version the link to the 0MAS file is not correctly specified. Try to paste the formula while the 0MAS is opened. Still, even if it was correclty working, it would most likely return the same result as the attached version (that i guess shouldn't be 2 but 1). In this case my hypothesis is: the formula doesn't filter the list by the dates. In 0MAS the 11/3 is the earlies date for a LMPX row? Sharing a file via mail will be a really last restort (after all this website is made for public solving). I'd try harder first.

Comment: Yes, 11/3 is the earliest date and OMAS is open at the same time. I only suggest using email for the sole purpose of sending you a copy of the actual file, which will give you the exact same data as I am working with, while the remainder of our conversation will occur on this forum, but I will continue to play with your formula and hopefully find a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I've added a formula to have a feedback about what cell the formula is targeting. Can you use it and report the result?

Comment: Sorry, I have been bedridden for the last couple of days. I will let you know as soon I can get around to it.

Comment: OK, I used your formula on the file: 11/09. I used it on a row when H>I and also on H<I. This is what the results were:                                                   
H<I:  Targeting cell D12 (value 44159), Sybol: A, Last: 114.68                              I also used the formula on a row where H<I:                                                        H>I: Targeting cell C3984 (value 44159), Sybol: ADS, Last: 75.06 ---
The problem is that the results are correct for H<I, but wrong for the other. It should be: Targeting cell C3979 (value 44152), Sybol: ADS, Last: 68.75

Comment: ALSO: I have used your formula on a couple of other files, just to see how it would work. When H<I, it seems to be working OK, but when H>I, I am having problems. I have tried it with the same day of dailys in OMAS and with the same day rows removed from OMAS. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, since the H>I case seems to be the problem, i've edited the feedback formula. Can you please use this version? I probably should have specified: please apply it on the same data you have given in the example.

Comment: I think the formula was cut off too early. Can you verify that it was supposed to end at: ....*1/ISNUMBER([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$C:$C)*1/([0MAS.xlsb]MAS!$A:$A=$A2),1)),""),"") & ", Starting data: " & $A2 & ", " & $B2 & ", " & $G2 & ", " & $H2 & ", " & $I2 & ", " & $M1

Comment: The formula is complete. Thank you.

Comment: I added a screenshot that shows the results of your formula on 11-02. The top 2 rows are H<I and the last 2 are H>I. I'm not positive what results you are searching for, so please advise me what else I need to do. I really want to thank you for spending so much time trying to help me. I've tried to figure out your formulas, but my lack of knowledge of Excel prevents me from comprehending what you're doing.

Comment: I am experiencing another problem. I am using three helper columns for each row, to do what your formula does and they seem to be working correctly, EXCEPT when I come to a place in the file that the formulas stop working. I have compared the formulas to the ones in the row above and they are the exact same formulas, except for the row number. In the cells that SHOULD have info in them, it shows nothing. I have turned off the automatic computation and restarted Excel, but got the same results. Any idea why the formulas would suddenly stop working?

Comment: The main problem with using all of these helper columns is that it slows my computer down...ALOT! The longest time so far has been a little over 22 minutes. It usually stops working for 10 minutes. I turned off the auto computation and am replacing the formulas with the values they found, to help speed up the process. Each file usually takes me 6 hours to process.

Comment: The debug formula had one main purpose: report what row of the list the original formula was targeting. Now i know that it's targeting the row 195659, which is not in the sample you grant. Assuming that the debug formula is working properly and that your image contains (also) the wanted result, this means that the relationship between H and I has lost importance; instead now the point is: what filter must be applied for that those previous rows to be ignored? I need you to check row 195659, confirm the data reported (3/11, LMPX, 21.18 of low) and tell me why the formula should ignore this row.

Comment: I didn't understad if your comment about the time the formula takes regards the original formula (the one that should solve your problem) or the debug formula (which won't be part of the solution). In any case: a formula based solution it's most likely to take a lot, since it has to compute all those ranges. We might try a VBA approach if you want. At least it wouldn't re-calculate the result anytime the sheet is recalculated. We could make it run just on demand.

Comment: I've also noticed an error in the debug formula (which now i've edited). The $M1 at the very end should have been M$1. My bad. Still it doesn't affect the previous conclusions and questions since all the remaining reference to M1 were correclty set as M$1. It just means that in the image the last value on the right (3, 1, 2 and 7) is to be ignored.

Comment: Sorry EVB, another bad day...just got up. I will check the file and try to answer your questions.

Comment: I took a screenshot of row 195659 of 11/3. I have no idea what I am supposed to be looking for. As for the amount of time it took for the formulas to run, I think you misunderstood which formulas I was talking about. I was referring to the formulas in the helper columns, not your formula. I know even less about VBA than I do about Excel, so I am not sure if that is an option...at this time.

Comment: EVB, I uploaded another screenshot of file 11-02, in which I used your formula on the 1st red cell (H>I). The earliest date for OMAS is 11/3. Does this provide you any info that you can use?

Comment: FYI, I added the rows for 11/2 to OMAS and got the exact same results.

Comment: Why do you have the same data of 199922 in row 195659? Did you remove 4000 rows? How can i make sense of the problem with a shifting data set? Ok, let's try it one more time: just use the debug formula on the [Book10 11-02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toHok.png) file in the cell K2 so it will target the row 2 (LMPX) only this time change the value of H2 to 4 so it will be greater than I (3.06). Also be sure that the value of M1 is equal to 1.

Comment: I'm unsure why the numbers changed. Maybe the 199922 was the number with the data from 11-02 added to 0MAS. Anyway, I updated BOOK10 to your specifications & made no changes to 0MAS, so hopefully this will help you figure out what I am doing wrong. I still think I should send you the raw data so you can manipulate instead of depending upon myself to do it correctly, but I will strive to work with whatever stipulations you want. You're the boss & I sincerely appreciate all that you do. I just wish I could return the favor. Let me know if you want me to send the files. Again, thanks so much!

Comment: The new file is entitled: NEW SCREENSHOT.

Comment: The formula seems to be targeting the right cell. Check it: if H>I we need to find the next LMPX row with a Low greater than Last+1 = 20.82+1 = 21.82, therefore row 195662 with a Low of 24.22. Shouldn't that be the correct answer?

Comment: I think I got you mixed up. I shouldn't be on here when I am running a 102 temperature.               
In your comment above, you are using BOOK10, where H2=4, then we would actually use 20.82-1, since H>I, and look up the next value, LOWER than 19.82, in column C!    I.E.  If H>I, we use B-1 and look in column C. If H<I, we use B+1 and look in Column D.                                                                     Does that make better sense? I am horrible at explaining things. Sorry for any problems and miscommunication.

Comment: EBM, You have spent more than enough time trying to help me, so you're fed up then I totally understand and will hold no grudge if you decide there's nothing else you can do to help. I am still working on your original formula to see if I can change it around to suit me needs.

Comment: Then of course my formula will not work in case of H>I. From your explanation, i meant it to look in column C for basically the same value it would have looked in column D were I>H. I'll change it in the next days. Hopefully this time for good. To be clear: in this case with H>I, we look in column C for the first value lower than 20.82-1=19.82 therefore 18.75 in row 195667. Do you confirm? Please take care of your health first.

Comment: Ok, i've just made a quick change that should probably be enouth but i will check again in the next days. Here it's late now and i should already have been sleeping, but i was confident enouth to change the formula while expecting it to work properly. We will check it. Also we can address the time-consuming problem. Maybe a VBA solution can be helpful. We will see.

Comment: CORRECT! Take your time, no big hurry. As for the time element, I have no idea how long your formula will take to work. I only have the helper formulas and that equals 4 formulas per row...to do what I am hoping your formula will do, using only 1 formula.

Comment: I confirm the formula. I've changed the debug formula too (just in case). You may try the solution formula and give a feedback. If it doesn't work properly, you can use the debug formula too. Tell me also if the solution formula takes too much time. We may try the VBA way.

Comment: I tried both formulas on BOOK10 and they both worked great! I have no idea how to thank you because of not only your great knowledge of Excel, but the huge amount of time you spent on this project. How can I ever thank you enough? I will try it on a daily file and see if I have any problems. I will let you know the results.

Comment: I have tried the formula on my daily file and it works perfectly. Thank you so much! If you need anything I can help you with, then please don't hesitate to ask. I have decided to start learning VBA. It certainly can't hurt. The ONLY "problems" is that the time it takes to computate and the file size isn't that much different than the helper column files, but that is no big deal. Again, thank you  S-O much!

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the answer as accepted then. I may try to put down some VBA code. I'll add to the answer in case.

Comment: I have been playing with the formula and I can say that it has produced great results. I have found several discrepancies between the helper column formulas and your formula, but when I manually double-checked the values, your formula has been 100% correct, so that makes me VERY happy. The only problem I am having is the great amount of time it takes for computation. I am experimenting by replacing formulas with the values they found. The OMAS file has grown to almost 400K rows, so I have cut it in half and also went to manual calculating, instead of automatic.

Comment: I double checked to ensure that my laptop was using all available threads and it is, which is 8. I will keep experimenting, to see if I can find some other option I can use to speed up the computation speed. If anyone has any ideas on how to speed things up, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not positive but I think the problem with the computation speed MIGHT be with my laptop. I have noticed that lately when I run Task Manager, the process freezes, so I need to go to the VIEW option and reset the the Update Speed. For some reason, it keeps automatically resetting the speed to Pause. This is a new thing. I have NEVER had this problem before.

Comment: I also made 1 change to your formula, which is:  $D:$D>=$B2+L$1, I.E., I added the "=".

Comment: I've added the VBA code. You may try it. I'm expecting it to be faster than the formula based solution (mostly because the latter has to cover thousands of times several columns of the list multiple times, which is really inefficient and costly). The code can be improved for multiple use on the same list (say adding an extra column that will make it skip a row already checked previously) as well as for other aspects. Let's just try it as it is. I didn't change its logic according to your last `>=` change. We might change it later.